# Contains function (set class) showing error in Visualforce inline statement

Tags: apex, visualforce, inline-visualforce

I am trying to set the selected attribute of a checkbox by comparing the associated name in apex:repeat row in a set. So if the set 'selectedProducts' has the name associated with the row of checkbox, it should be checked, otherwise not. But when I use the contains method to check whether the name is present in the set, i am getting the error "Unknown function selectedProducts.contains. Check spelling". Can anyone guide me why I am getting this error.

VF Code

```
<apex:outputPanel id="productList">
          <div class="collection">
            <apex:repeat value="{!wrapPrivateLabelList}" var="plabel">
              <div class="product">
                <div class="pimage">
                  <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!plabel.selected}" id="inputId" selected="{!IF(selectedProducts.contains(plabel.privateLabel.Name),true,false)}"/>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!plabel.privateLabel.Product_Image__c}"></apex:outputField>
                </div>

                <div class="pname">
                  <apex:outputText value="{!plabel.privateLabel.Name}"></apex:outputText>
                </div>
                

              </div>

            </apex:repeat>
          </div>

        </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a practical matter, you can use contains in Apex via a custom getter/setter. I've used this to make it easier to get a hold of the selected items in the controller:

```
public class q334520 {
    public class Wrapper {
        Set<String> selectedItems;
        public String itemValue { get; set; }
        public Boolean isSelected {
            get { 
                return selectedItems.contains(itemValue); 
            }
            set { 
                if(value) {
                    selectedItems.add(itemValue);
                } else { 
                    selectedItems.remove(itemValue);
                }
            }
        }
        Wrapper(Set<String> controllerSelectedItems, String value) {
            selectedItems = controllerSelectedItems;
            itemValue = value;
        }
    }

    Set<String> selectedItems;
    public String getSelectedItemsAsCSV() {
        return String.join(new List<String>(selectedItems),',');
    }
    public Wrapper[] items { get; set; }
    public q334520() {
        items = new Wrapper[0];
        selectedItems = new Set<String>();
        String[] itemValues = new String[] { 'a','b','c','d','e' };
        for(String itemValue: itemValues) {
            items.add(new Wrapper(selectedItems, itemValue));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page controller="q334520">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:actionStatus startText="Working..." stopText="Waiting..." id="status" />
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!items}" var="item">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!item.isSelected}" label="{!item.itemValue}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" status="status" reRender="form"/>
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        {!selectedItemsAsCSV}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

The main trick here, is we have a common Set that is passed in to each wrapper, so when it modifies the value, the controller sees this change. You don't need to use an onchange handler, either (this was for demonstration purposes only), you can simply read the values on your action method when the user clicks a button.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call arbitrary Apex functions in Visualforce's expression language.

The usual pattern for this type of implementation in Visualforce is to define a wrapper class. The wrapper class holds a `selected` attribute alongside an sObject or data members:

```
class Wrapper {
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}
    public Product2 product {get; set;}
}
```

The controller digests selection details and the records being manipulated into a `List<Wrapper>`, using whatever Apex logic is necessary. Then, the Visualforce `<apex:repeat>` markup iterates over the `List<Wrapper>` property of the controller, and binds the values of the selected checkbox and other controls to the wrapper's members.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have the wrapper class built and the records are shown using the wrapper list. But there is a drop down list which is used to toggle through different pages and when pages are toggled, I want to retain the selection of the checkboxes that were already checked. For that purpose  I stored the name of products that have checkbox turned on in a set variable. So is there a way to compare the content of set and check/uncheck the checboxes?

Comment: Not in Visualforce markup. You have to do it in Apex. But it shouldn't require any extra work, on my read: store the selection data _in the wrapper classes_, not in a set.

Comment: @DavidReed You can use a set, it actually makes life a lot easier in the end. See my example (but yours is fine, too!).